# php5.6-fpm with nginx on ubuntu 16.04 receiving no data

Tags: php, nginx, ubuntu-16.04, fpm

I have just installed ubuntu 16.04 and php5.6-fpm and nginx. 
nginx server block is as follows:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location ^~ /.git/{
            deny all;
    }

location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php5.6-fpm.socket;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    }

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
 }
```

Now when i take localhost, it shows me nothing. No data received. Response code 200.

If i try to access any static file. It works fine. Eg: localhost/xyz.png will show the image.
But no data is received when trying to run a php script.
It doesn't matter if script file is present or not. Response for a php script is constant. i.e no data but 200 ok response.

Please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes i tried with everything like phpinfo(); or <?php echo "helloworld"; etc. Nothing works. Thanks anyways.

Comment: Nothing. Both nginx and php5.6-fpm logs are empty.

Comment: if you are talking about view-source:http://localhost/.
Yes this source file is empty. Moreover the response section in firefox console is empty too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add `SCRIPT_FILENAME`:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    # add this:
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
```

Comment: You made/saved my day. Why was this working on ubuntu 14.04 with same settings?